# JavaScript: Fudged up a CodeCademy tutorial

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a JavaScript tutorial at codecademy.com

It starts by giving you the following outline for a function

```
var getReview = function (movie) {

};
```

Then it gives you a list of movies, and it tells you to write a function so that it returns a review for a movie based on whatever movie was passed in as a parameter. The question also suggests that you use a switch statement.  Below is what I came up with but it's not the correct answer. Codecademy doesn't unfortunately reveal the answer.  I thought it was weird to put a switch statement in a function, but that's what it said had to be done.

Can anyone explain what I did wrong?

```
var getReview = function(movie) {

var result;

switch (movie) {

  case "Matrix":
    result = "good trip out";
    break;

  case "Princess Bride":
    result = "awesome date night movie";  
    break;

  case "Welcome to America":
    result = "Amjad's favorite";
    break;

    case "Remember the Titans":
    result = "love the sports";
    break; 

    case "Why do I look like I'm 12?":
    result = "The Ryan and Zach story"
    break; 

    case "Fighting Kangaroos in the wild";
    result = "Token Australian movie for Leng"
    break; 

    default:
    result = "I don't know";
}

return result; 
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
case "Fighting Kangaroos in the wild";
```

Should be a colon, not a semi-colon.

Also a few semi-colons missing after the lines that assign to `result`.

Since a function is a reusable block of code - any code - a switch statement is perfectly legitimate inside one. In this case it's necessary because the function needs to compare the passed `movie` against a list of possible cases.

p.s. if you're new to JS, get into the habit of good indentation, too :) It'll stand you in good stead.